# Flutter and Android Release Mode

Tags: android, flutter, release

How I can find out crash logs in release mode in a flutter. In the android studio, I  am not able to get crash logs where the app is going to crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get logs in release mode. If you want to collect crash logs in release mode please check crashlytics(free) product in firebase. With this product, you can remotely receive logs without connecting mobile to your computer.

Answer (score 0):

To easily get crash logs, you can embed `Firebase` into your project and enable crash reporting into your flutter project.
So after the subscription, you can go to `CrashAnalytics` from your Firebase console and be able to see crash logs.

For more information on how to set up Firebase into your flutter application, check here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup

Answer (score 0):

Android studio has a logcat right at the bottom. Although you might see a lot of extra things you don't need, but if a major error occurs in your app it'll show up there. You can also search with the title of your app for more refined results.
[image: Logcat]

Answer (score 0):

One another option in Android studio is to select Run > Flutter Run 'Main.dart' in release mode from top menu. You can see all logs in console. Try putting a break point if you want.